# I have 4 columns . 2 columns of suppliers for 2017 and 2018 with respective dollar amounts. Return dollar while comparing suppliers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A is suppliers of 2017
Column B is total $ spent for that supplier in 2017 
Column C is suppliers of 2018
Column D is total $ spent for that supplier in 2018

Column E= Sum of total $ for 2017& 2018 for respective suppliers (i.e compare suppliers, find a match and then sum it up).

I am finding a hard time to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure if the sum in column E should match 2017 suppliers or 2018 suppliers, but the following formula wold work if you created a list of unique suppliers in column F and pasted the following formula in column G for the total spent by each supplier.

[image: Layout for formulas to work]

```
{=SUM(IF(F2=$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$6))+SUM(IF(F2=$C$2:$C$6,$D$2:$D$6))}
```

Note: This is an array formula. You need to paste it into the cell, then enter `ctrl+shift+enter`. Then you can paste that cell down the column.

Two `SUMIFS` formulas would also work as well

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6,F4)+SUMIFS($D$2:$D$6,$C$2:$C$6,F4)
```

Comment: I have made a few developments.

Comment: Change in objective.

I have column A(suppliers of 2017&2018), Column B(sum of $ for suppliers of 2017&18), column C is complete list of all our suppliers.

Objective: Comapre column A and C, if there is a match Column D should give me respective $.

Comment: In that case, a simple `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,C2)` pasted in `D2` and pasted down your list should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Are the same suppliers in the same row?  If not you can use the following:
sumifs(B,A,"Supplier X") + sumifs(D,C,"Supplier X") for each supplier.

Comment: Change in objective. I have column A(suppliers of 2017&2018), Column B(sum of $ for suppliers of 2017&18), column C is complete list of all our suppliers. Objective: Comapre column A and C, if there is a match Column D should give me respective $.